# Boost::Serialization VS2015 compile error in Release Mode Mnly

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, visual-studio-2015

I am building a project that uses Boost:Serialization fairly heavily, & am getting errors during the linking process, though only when built in release mode, the errors are:

fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.

&

fatal error C1002: compiler is out of heap space in pass 2

I only get these errors when building in Release mode, using the v140 toolchain, built in Visual Studio 2015, on both windows 8 & 10.

If built using the LLVM 2014 toolchain, it builds with no errors.

If I comment out the boost::serialization stuff, the code will compile in Release mode, so I also am assuming it has something to do with how v140 is optimizing the templated serialization code, but the crash happens during the linking phase, not while compiling...

Has anyone run into either of these errors before? Or seen code that will build in debug but not in release?

Thank You!

Comment: Have you tried [using the 64-bit toolchain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x4d2c09s%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)? There's a way to specify that for a Visual Studio project as well, as described in a comment [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/10/30/the-visual-c-linker-best-practices-developer-iteration.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The error pretty much says it all: "fatal error C1002: compiler is out of heap space in pass 2" - it's exceeding the resource limits while instantiating and trying to inline the many templates of Boost Serialization. It's totally possible that the newer link-time optimization capabilities are at fault here.

See

- [/GL (Whole Program Optimization)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zza0de8.aspx)

So, try to disable that, if it is enabled: `/GL-`